# What is the probability of rejection in rejection sampling?

Tags: monte-carlo, rejection-sampling

**Context:** I'm reading up on sampling in [MCMC for Machine Learning](http://cis.temple.edu/~latecki/Courses/RobotFall07/PapersFall07/andrieu03introduction.pdf). On page 5, it mentions rejection sampling:

```
repeat
  sample xi ~ q(x) and u ~ U(0,1)
  if uMq(xi) < p(xi):
    accept xi
until enough samples
```

(where $M$ is chosen such that $p(x) \le Mq(x)$ for all $x$)

**Question:** In the analysis, the paper says that it may work bad for high-dimensional settings. While I can see that, the paper gives a reason that I don't understand: $P(x \text{ accepted}) = P \left(u < \frac{p(x)}{Mq(x)} \right) = \frac{1}{M}$. This doesn't make sense to me. If the probability were constant, why even bother to evaluate $p(x)$? Should this be a "at most $\frac{1}{M}$? Or am I just misinterpreting the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment in the paper refers to the fact that the value is rejected (M-1) out of M times.  The distribution of p(x) depends on the accepted values not on how frequently a chosen value is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of rejection is just what it says, in your case it is dominated by $1/M$, but it's value depends on $x$. In higher dimension, the pdf $p(x)$ is multidimensional, but you still require a pdf $q(x)$ such that $Mq(x)$ strictly dominates $p(x)$. Because this can be hard to find if $p$ does not have a classical distribution, your best option is to take $q$ as a standard distribution (like multivariate Gaussian) and increase $M$, which makes the algorithm less efficient.